# How to calculate the d-band from pdos data?

Tags: quantum-espresso, density-of-states, matlab, d-band

I am trying to find the d-band center of pdos data generated using quantum espresso 6.8.
I'm aware that this maybe calculated by the formula:

$$ \frac{\int_{-\infty}^\infty E \cdot \textrm{pdos}(E)dE}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty \textrm{pdos}(E)dE} \tag{1}$$

I tried XMgrace as suggested [here](https://lists.quantum-espresso.org/pipermail/users/2014-September/030667.html) but was not able to do it. Is there a way to use this formula using MatLab, or any other software to integrate the pdos curve (maybe a piece of code)? Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: if you have E and pdos(E) data, you can use trapz function in matlab to integrate numerator and denominator of equation. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trapz.html

Comment: That worked. Thank you @pranavkumar

Comment: @pranavkumar Can you turn that into an answer?

Comment: @pranavkumar Nike has a good point. If you can provide even a little more detail about this process, an answer is much more visible for future users (and much less likely to disappear than a comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numerical integration for evenly-spaced data can be performed using `trapz` function in `MATLAB`. Here infinite integration can assumed to integrate between extrema of data.

```
d_center=trapz(E,P)/trapz(E)
```

**Trapezoidal rule of integration**

$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\frac{b-a}{2N}( f(x_{1})+2f(x_{2})...+2f(x_{n})+f(x_{n+1}))$